# HTTPS request only in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, webserver

My question might be confusing and I will try to make it clear as possible! We have a webserver(Apache), application server(Spring boot) and database server. I am implementing HTTPS for the rest API. SSL certificates are set to be in web server and the web server will redirect all requests to the Application Server.

My question is as I have added my SSL certificates in webserver, do I need to add anything to my application server? How do I make my spring boot application to accept only HTTPS request?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please research before posting a question: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https

Comment: Thank you for your link. I did research, but I am confused! When you add the SSL certificate in web server, do you need to add the certificate again in application server? Can you please help?

Comment: Yes, you will need a certificate on each server.

Comment: Thank you Aniket

Comment: Do note that the certificate is required only if these servers are physically separated and are talking to each other over a wire.

Comment: Yes, they are physically separated :)